# Create auto configure spring library to spring-boot application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am creating a library which uses spring 4.3.0.One of the spring-boot application will consume this library. Currently i am using @ComponentScan in the main class of spring-boot application to scan the beans inside library instead i want to auto-configure it.So what i did is i created a configuration class inside the library and declared @ComponentScan in the configuration file.

After consuming the library in spring-boot application it is not scanning the beans inside library and throws,

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.sample.book.client.service.BookService] found for dependency [com.sample.book.client.service.BookService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1057)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
... 33 common frames omitted
```

How to resolve this error ? Why Spring scanning @service classes before @Configuration?

Your help should be appreciable and i will provide code-samples if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your config is not loaded by default from your Boot Application.
I also guess that you have not added

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```

to your Boot Application.

So you can try to add your config to the Annotation @EnableAutoConfiguration to be loaded by your application. Then the Configuration that you put in [META-INF/spring.factories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-locating-auto-configuration-candidates) inside your library-JAR is automatically loaded.

Or you can `@Import` your configuration in your `@SpringBootApplication` class

Comment: My spring boot application is already annotated with @SpringBootApplication so again declaring SpringBootApplication would be redundant.Also you have specified "META-INF/spring.factories", my library is using spring not spring-boot so How can i specify the auto-configuration with following import "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration" ? "EnableAutoConfiguration" is provided by spring-boot not spring please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: When you app is allready a @ SpringBootApplication then you have AutoConfiguration enabled. Then you can put a META-INF/spring-factories inside your library JAR or you can @ Import your Configuration of your Library

Comment: It works.Thank you. I followed the META-INF/spring.factories" method and it works like a charm but could you please define the @Import or could you please share a link about "@Import"?

Comment: With @ [Import](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html)  you can import @ Configuration classes

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that most probable cause is that your library resides in a different package than your spring boot application (and its sub-packages). When annotating a class with @SpringBootApplication you also get @ComponentScan annotation set to its default (that is scanning components in a package where a given class resides).

Personally, I prefer to create a @Configuration annotated class in my library projects. Such class is responsible for proper library setup (declaring component scan and so on). Later, in dependent project I use an @Import annotation to import that configuration class (and corresponding beans).

Answer (score 3):

I like the import. But I wanted to avoid any imports or package scan in client code.

I built my-lib (spring-boot)

by defining, Configuration in resources/META-INF/spring.factories

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
 com.fanniemae.ebrms.dsrunner.DecisionServiceRunnerConfiguration
```

added componentScan in my configuration (my-lib)

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DecisionServiceRunnerProperties.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.xyz.dsrunner.*" })
public class DecisionServiceRunnerConfiguration {
```

and just included as dependency in my client spring boot application.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Import({MailServiceConfig.class, ServiceConfig.class})
```

can be use for enable the specific configurations;

http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch04s03.html